# Power Spectra density and FFT

Tags: matlab

I know it may be a basic question but I am having trouble with the limits when applying the fft function in Matlab.
I have a time series from this specifications:

```
bdf=0.005;
fHighCut=0.2;
maxTime=600;
freq=1/maxTime:df:fHighCut;
w=2*pi*freq;
time=linspace(0,600,length(freq)*10);
```

My time series lloks like: 
[image]

The length of it is 400s. I want to create the PSD from it but it appears that I am obtaining the symetric as well like:[image]

with this commands:

```
timestepFFT=1/time(end);
freqFFT=(1:length(time))*1/time(end);
amplitudeEtaSeries=abs(fft(etaSeries)/length(time));
powerSpectrumEtaSeries=amplitudeEtaSeries.^2/timestepFFT;
powerSpectrumEtaSeries(1)=0;
```

Can you please help me? THanks

Comment: you need to use also `fftshift` , read here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html

Answer (score 1):

Please read this article. power spectral density calculation by using fft always produce the symmetric PSD. So ignore second half of fft output and details can be found here:
http://www.mathworks.se/help/signal/ug/psd-estimate-using-fft.html